# Text between horizontal lines not aligning center when width is applied

Tags: css

When you give width to the line, the `text-align: centre` doesn't work how do I solve this?

```css
.line-center {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2><span class="line-center">Test</span></h2>
```

Comment: `h2:after { transform: translateY(-50%) }`?

Comment: not working......

Comment: ) How to reproduce the error?

Comment: The text looks like it's centred in the code you've provided.

Comment: I mean the whole ----txt---- in the center of the page

Answer (score 0):

As you have given a width to the element you could use `h2 { margin: 0 auto; }` to set the left and right margins equal (within the containing element)

```css
.line-center {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2><span class="line-center">Test</span></h2>
```